# Scale Windows Azure roles programmatically

Tags: azure

I am looking for some code that will scale a role to a given amount of instances given the roleID I want to scale.  I am looking for someone to implement this method.

```
Private Shared Sub DoScaleOperation(RoleID As String, InstanceCount As Integer)
    'TODO:
    'Check if the current number of instances in the role RoleID matches InstanctCount
    'and if the numbers don't match then scale down or scale up as appropriate.
End Sub
```

This method should work for both the dev environment and the cloud environment.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Also out curiorsity I an wondering what the names of the Role Instances will be on a scale up and what will be the names of the instances removed during a scale down.  I am hoping the names of the instances will be something like RoleID_(0 to InstanceCount - 1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an API that you want to call in order to programmatically change instance count in Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx  This API does not work in local dev environment.  You will need to provide a management certificate with your call.
You can also use Azure cmdlets to change instance counts.

Comment: I need to have certain events execute before a role scales down to make sure I flush out certain data belonging to a role instance so a typical auto scale approach won't work for me.  I do not understand the rest api, to me  it looks like ancient chinese.  So I was wondering if anyone could provide me with the method?

Comment: Understood.  Here are a few articles on the topic. http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/windows-azure-and-scaling-how and http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/corrado/archive/2011/02/09/how-to-programmatically-change-the-number-of-azure-role-instances.aspx and there are a few more that show how to use cmdlets if you google enough.  There is no magic "one line of code" unless it is a cmdlet

Comment: You can handle the OnStop() event to execute shutdown code in your role instances. This keeps your shutdown sequence independent from the code that scales you (and you don't want to have scale code within the same instance you're scaling). Also, your role instances need to recover gracefully when they're shut down unexpectedly (such as with a hardware failure).

Comment: Yes, If something goes wrong like a hardware failure during my OnStop event, this would be no good.  This is why I needed to implement my own scaling code, the role that gets sclaed down needs to give permission by releasing any locks that belong to it before it actually gets scaled down.

Comment: Ryan, I don't think you will ever be able to "catch" real hardware failures.  If there is a hard-stop, your instance will crash and there will be little you can do.  However, you should use OnStop() method to place cleanup logic.  This logic will fire when instances are scaled down by any auto-scaling solution as well as when Windows Azure will decide to reboot/upgrade your instance (this usually happens once a month due to OS upgrades).

Comment: As far as I know, when one of my roles crashes due to hardware failure, the azure health monitor will detect this, make sure the instance is really dead and then re instantiate the instance on another machine, my role knows how to pick up where it left off since it writes it's state to table storage.  So long as there isn't any duplicates of the same instanceID running at the same time I should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have looked at [WASABi, the Autoscaling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)?

What were your conclusions for the P&P product in your scenario?