# Create Azure Worker Role or Cloud Service in Code?

Tags: api, azure

Can anyone say if there is a complete/accessible API for the latest Azure bits that will allow the complete creation (not just scale out like [Scale Windows Azure roles programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650903/scale-windows-azure-roles-programmatically)) of a 'worker role' application? Not building a web site or needing any SQL or table storage. I would like to build an EXE that will create the full container and allow the upload of DLL/config artifacts so the app will exist and start up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this completely solves your challenge, but... Take a look at these PowerShell cmdlets:

- [`New-AzureServiceProject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205199.aspx)
- [`Add-AzureWebRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205203.aspx)
- [`Add-AzureWorkerRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205175.aspx)

They will spin the scaffold code for your web and worker role, respectively, and optionally allow you to specify a template folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [Operations on Hosted Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460812.aspx) page should get you started.  Specifically you'll want to Create a Hosted Service if you don't have it already, then Create a Deployment.  You'll have to point to a deployment in blob storage that you've uploaded in order to create and then start the deployed instances.